# How can one read the order of convergence from a loglog-graph?

Tags: convergence-divergence, monte-carlo

I am making a task which includes running a Monte Carlo simulation and calculating the order of convergence experimentally. I have to calculate (or approximate) the order of convergence using different methods.

One method is reading it from the loglog-graph. I know that the ***rate*** of convergence can be read by retrieving the slope of this graph. The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to read the ***order*** of convergence from the graph.

So my question is: how can the order of convergence be read from the loglog-graph?

Comment: please specify what exactly you mean by convergence rate/order

Comment: @user251257 I mean the convergence of the difference between the real value and the approximated value. This difference, the error, converges to zero and I would like to know its convergence order. The loglog-graph I mentioned has the number of sampling points N on the x-axis and the error on the y-axis.

Comment: say $x_N$ is the approximation given by the first $N$ samples. $x_N$ converges to $x$ with order $p$ if $|x_N - x| \le C n^{-p}$ for some suitable $C$, right?

Comment: I've taken some math-based statistics and I still have trouble understanding what you mean. Can you explicitly define what is the ORDER of convergence, versus what is the RATE of convergence, in explicit terms? I'm familiar with asymptotic estimate expressions, even in statistics expressions, so I think if you can do this, then I (or at least, somebody) should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the real value of output variable is $\alpha$. Following relation provides you the value of output variable for $n$ iterations.
$$\alpha_{MC}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_i$$
Where $i\in[1,n]$ are the iterations and $a_i$ is the value of output variable for $i^{th}$ iteration. Hence the error in the final output of MC is:
$$\xi=\alpha-\alpha_{MC}$$
**How to draw the convergence:**
Calculate the average of MC's output after each iteration using aforemetioned relation. You will have $[\alpha_{MC_1}, \alpha_{MC_2}....\alpha_{MC_n}]$. Plot this list versus the number of iteration and another constant line representing the real value. The plot will look like this:[image: Convergence MC]

Here is a python code to do this:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

# Declare output vectors
V=[]
V2=[]
V_ref=[]
# Change directory to fetch input csv files

os.chdir(r"C:") #result file

# open the input file to read data

with open('xx.csv',newline='') as csvFile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        V1=float(row[1])
        V2.append(V1)

V3=V2[0]
V.append(V3)
V3=(V2[1]+V[0])/2
V.append(V3)
for i in range(len(V2)-2):
   V3=(V2[i+2]+V[i+1]*(i+1))/(i+2)
   V.append(V3)

X=range(len(V))
plt.plot(X,V,'r')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```